# jQuery toggle() text in separate element

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am having some trouble getting a toggle function to work and need someone to help explain it to me.

My HTML (simplified):

```
<div id="filter_names"></div>

<div class="item">Option 1</div>
<div class="item">Option 2</div>
<div class="item">Option 3</div>
<div class="item">Option 4</div>
```

My jQuery (simplified)

```
$(".item").click(function(){

  var tagname = $(this).html();
  $('#filter_names').append(' > '+tagname);

  $(".loading").show();

});
```

As you can see I am appending clicked items' value to the div at the top. This works fine, but i need it to be removed when i click it again.

I am pretty sure it needs a toggle() function but so far my attempts have been pretty fruitless.

Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** You can see what i want to achieve in this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djBPa/). It's working exactly how i want it to by appending a value to the end (like a breadcrumb link), but is not being removed when i click it again.

Comment: see my updated answer..with demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the #filter_names contents and check if the clicked tag's value is already included, then remove it if it is, or add it otherwise:

```
  if (filternames.indexOf(tagname) === -1) {
    $('#filter_names').append(' > '+tagname);
  } else {
    $('#filter_names').text(filternames.replace(' > '+tagname, ''));
  }
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/passcod/Kz3vx/

Note that you might get weird results if one tag's value is contained in another's.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you for explaining it for me. I am beginning to understand jQuery more and more each day. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".item").click(function(){
        var $this=$(this);
        var tagname = ' > ' +$this.html();
        //if has item-check class remove tag from filter_names
        if($this.hasClass("item-click")){
            var h=$("#filter_names").text();
            $("#filter_names").text(h.replace(tagname, '' ));
        }
        else{
            $('#filter_names').append(tagname);
        }
        $(this).toggleClass("item-click").toggleClass("item");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Almost there... Need to remove the `>` also.

Comment: @Alex R. It is removing `>` as `> Item 1 > Item 2 > Item 3` now if you click on `Item 1` it `#filter_names` will have `> Item 2 > Item 3`

Answer (score 0):

try this one...

```
 $(this).toggleClass("item-click item");
```

this will add these classes alternatively when you click on div. or if you just want to remove this class  on second click then you should write this in your click handler.

```
if( $(this).hasClass("item-click")){

     $(this).removeClass("item-click");
}
```

**EDITED** -----
to remove appended html you can try this...

```
 if($(this).hasClass("item-click")){
            $("#filter_names").text("");
        }
        else{
            $('#filter_names').append(tagname);
        }
```

it's working [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/a3xaK/)

hope this helps you!!

Comment: I believe that kills it after the first click because the selector will no longer be able to find the original clicked ".item"

Comment: Sorry, this is not what i'm after. I need the value of the clicked "item" div to go to the "filter_names" div and then have it removed when the div is clicked again. The toggleClass is just a little extra thing I have there, just ignore it.

Comment: It's ok, i should remove that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you want to remove it when you clicked on same div or any div with class item?

Answer (score 0):

I like passcod's solution - here's an alternative that wraps the elements in divs and puts them in alphabetical order.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g_thom/udUWj/). The sort function is from http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/jquery-sorting-elements/.

```
$(".item").click(function(){
    var tagname = $(this).html();
    var target = $('#filter_names').find('div:contains("> ' + tagname + '")');
    if (target.is('*')) {
        target.remove();
    }
    else $('#filter_names').append('<div class="appended"> > '+ tagname +'<div>');  
    function sortAlpha(a,b) {
        return a.innerHTML > b.innerHTML ? 1 : -1;
    }
    $('#filter_names div').sort(sortAlpha).appendTo('#filter_names');
});
```